# How can I achieve more control over my XFCE keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, xfce, window-manager

XFCE has a great keyboard commands editor in the window manager keyboard settings area. I can change the commands that open or close windows or move to workspaces etc. But it is a bit lacking.

What if I want the search prompt from alt+f2 to be called up by the home key instead?

Or what if I want the media button on my keyboard to launch my default media app etc?